# Flutter, set state() from parent widget called by not rendering

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three screen.

1. Home screen. 2 Mortgage Screen. 3. New branch Screen. [Each Mortgage can have one or more branches]
2. The home screen shows a list of all current mortgages a user ended, with a summary of each the branches in each mortgages.
3. When the user clicks on one of the mortgages in the list in screen 1, he gets to screen 2 which shows all the details of the branches of that mortgage. User can add new branch by clicking floating action button, to get to page 3.
4. In page 3, the user fills out a form to add a new branch. Once a branch is added, page 3 is popped, and page 2 is still appearing.

When page 3 is done, a new branch is added to the selected mortgage, and it is supposed to update the data displayed in page 2 and in page 1. I have done this by passing callback methods into pages 2 and 1, and then calling set state in both classes.

Page 2 is updated and displays fine. However, when I go back from page 2 to page 1, page 1 has not updated. Even though the setState method is called in page 1.

I hope its clear, I will add the code of page 1, and maybe you can help me see why the page is not rerendering.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  List<MaslulModel> savedMaslulim = <MaslulModel>[];

  List<MortgageModel> savedMortgages = <MortgageModel>[];

  // THIS METHOD IS CALLED FROM PAGE 2.
  notifyHomeScreen() async {

    print('2124: notifyHomeScreen called in home_screen');

    savedMaslulim.clear();
    savedMortgages.clear();

    savedMaslulim = await SharedPrefsMethods.getMaslulListFromPrefs();

    for (var i = 0; i < savedMaslulim.length; i++) {
      print(savedMaslulim[i].getDetails());
    }

    savedMortgages = sortOutMaslulimToMortgages(savedMaslulim);

    setState(() {
      print('2124: Set state. Maslul at 0 List size: ${savedMortgages[0].maslulList.length}');
    });

  }

  TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  String codeDialog = '';
  String valueText = '';

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('InitState');

    asyncGetSavedMortgages();

  }

  void asyncGetSavedMortgages() async {


    savedMaslulim = await SharedPrefsMethods.getMaslulListFromPrefs();

    savedMortgages = sortOutMaslulimToMortgages(savedMaslulim);

    print(savedMortgages.length);
    
    setState(() {
      print('Set state called');
    });

  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    for (var i = 0; i < savedMortgages.length; i++) {
      if(savedMortgages[i].name=='tonight'){
        print('2124: From HOME: ${savedMortgages[i].maslulList.length}');
      }

    }

    return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate('my_mortgages'))),

        drawer: MainDrawer(),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {

          // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/new_mortgage_screen');
          _displayTextInputDialog(context);

        },
        label: Text('הוסף משכנתא'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),

    body:  ListView.builder(
    itemCount: savedMortgages.length,
    key: Key(savedMortgages.length.toString()),

    itemBuilder: (context, index){

      for (var i = 0; i < savedMortgages.length; i++) {
        if(savedMortgages[i].name=='tonight'){
          print('2124: From HOME itemBuilder: ${savedMortgages[i].maslulList.length}');
        }

      }

    return MortgageSummaryWidget(savedMortgages[index], notifyHomeScreen: notifyHomeScreen );

    },
      

      ),
    );

  }

  Future<void> _displayTextInputDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('הכנס שם של המשנכתא:'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  valueText = value;
                });
              },
              controller: _textFieldController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "שם"),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                textColor: Colors.red,
                child: Text('בטל'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('בצע'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    codeDialog = valueText;


                    if(codeDialog.isEmpty){
                      showAlertDialog(context, 'שגיאה', 'לא הכנסת שם מסלול');
                      return;
                    }

                    Navigator.pop(context);

                    // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/new_mortgage_screen');
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NewMortgageScreen(notifyParent: notifyHomeScreen, title: codeDialog,)));

                    // Navigator.pushNamed(
                    //     context,
                    //     '/new_mortgage_screen',
                    //     arguments: {'mortgageName': codeDialog}
                    // );

                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }



}
```

All the values are updated, but the screen display isn't.

I cannot figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Try to call `setState` if needed in `Navigator.push(context, screen).then((_) => setState(() {});`. This is called after you call `pop` from another screen and go back to the previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the problem, I was sending a parameter into the State, and this wan't getting updated. I changed it to get the parameter by using widget.parameter.